# Is there any way to detect single color plane, in Arcore to place objects?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have been looking at the [Introduction to Sceneform example from code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/#0). Everything works but I want to detect single (solid) colour planes as well. As I know ARcore can detect planes only with some pattern or strongly contrasting wall surfaces. Is there any way to detect a single colour plane or a manual way to place an object on a single colour plane, with all other controls (rotate, move) of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, single color plane detection does not work well. One of the options would be to use marker approach as to use Augmented Images API. So you place your target image on that plane.